# how to split a 40" model into 5 parts to print seperate

Tags: 3d-models, stl, fusion360

I currently have a model in fusion 360 of cylinders with the largest being 40" diameter in a specific pattern as seen below. My printer is a Ender-3x with the build plate dimensions of 8.7" x 8.7" x 9.8"

I need to break this model into 5 pieces of exactly equivalent length so I can print same piece 5 times to equal a full cylinder

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several options:

### Generate full-size STL, cut via software later

If you just have an STL, you can use software such as Meshmixer to modify it. In this case, a plain `plane cut` would suffice.

### Modifiy the design file

A better way is to go into the design file (in your case fusion) and modify it there. In your case, it's rather easy:

- add a construction plane

  - choose the right constraints, e.g. an angle to the XZ plane or a distance to the XY plane
- choose the model

  - `Edit > split model`
  - choose the construction plane you made
- rinse and repeat

If you want to get rid of parts that became superfluous after this, use the `remove` option, not the `delete` option, as the later tries to make sure that the object never was made in the workflow.

Comment: While this works I realized I can't delete the remaining objects that I don't need without it reverting the split and putting the object back together.  more then likely something in doing wrong

Comment: @Ragekillen use `remove`.

Comment: I might add that it might be simpler to cut into 6 or 8 sections for symmetry.  And more important: redesign the subsection with some sort of interlocking tabs to facilitate assembly.  And don't pull a Morton-Thiokol!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft for radial cuts? yes. I actually prefer to make interlocking parts with some complex cutter (Dovetail is lovely), but those are not simple...

Comment: thanks everyone. I completed my model yesterday and @Carl Witthoft I already had thought about interlocking tabs so i made small cylinders that will slide into an equivalent sized whole( most likely will have to super glue them for a finishing touch but o well).  finished product can be seen here if interested   https://gyazo.com/b7469709c80d776467f8aaf4acb3de15